# Jmeter: Using CSV file with uneven columns to test drive sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, data-driven

I have a csv file that has a list of stores. For every Store there are 10 departments.
I will need to make a GET API call for all the 10 departments in 100 stores. So my columns in CSV file are not eve. I will have column A with 100 store IDs, and column B with 10 department IDs.
How can I use every Store ID 10 times (once with every department ID) in Jmeter sampler?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - the only way is splitting your CSV file into 2 separate files

If the CSV file comes from external source and cannot be changed - you can consider using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller - Store__idx') as int).split('\,')[0],)}
```

Given example CSV file `test.csv` with the following contents:

```
store1,department1
store2,department2
,department3
,department4
,department5
,department6
,department7
,department8
,department9
,department10
```

You can achieve your requirement using below approach:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank your answer. It looks like it has to be using some coding as I will need to user the Store and the department as parameter in the same call. Otherwise the loop image it great.

Comment: It's not a problem to put both functions into a single request